# Returning a value to shell script from a node.js file

Tags: node.js, shell

I am calling a NodeJS file like this in a shell script:

```
$ node process.js
$ let "errors |= $?"
```

I want to see if the process.js file returned any errors. How do I return a value inside process.js file so that I can capture it in my shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the exitCode (and let the node process die naturally):

```
process.exitCode = 1
```

Or you can force-kill it:

```
process.exit(1)
```

in both cases it will return `1` as the exit code.

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code